# Mod rewrite, set parameter order?

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

Ok so I am trying to rewrite

http://example.com/post.php?cat1=aCatagory&title=aTitle

to

http://example.com/aCatagory/aTitle

The problem is I don't really want people to be able to go to the page using

http://example.com/aTitle/aCatagory

Is it possible in mod rewrite to stop/handle this. Ideally give a 404 as though the directory does not exist? Would this be considered best practice?, as I don't want two ways to access one page :/

As you can probably tell i'm not too good at mod rewrite yet.

Is this even possible? This question's been up for a day and still no answers or comments! :o

Any help would be great :)

Many Thanks

EDIT my current rule

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ([^.]+)/([^.]+)$ post.php?cat1=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what the problem is. If the first part is always the `cat1` value and the second part is always the `title` value then the second shouldn't be a problem. Just return a 404 in your script as you normally would.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,the problem is that the aCatagory and aTitle are parameter values, It does not matter to my script in what order the parameters are given in the URL eg http://example.com/post.php?cat1=aCatagory&title=aTitle Or http://example.com/post.php?title=aTitle&cat1=aCatagory. When this is re-written I only want people to be able to access http://example.com/aCatagory/aTitle and not the other way around

Comment: But... you're... only going to be passing the first segment of the path as `cat1`, and the second as `title`. How do you expect them to spontaneously swap places?

Comment: I just don't like the idea that for example, Google will see both http://example.com/aCatagory/aTitle and http://example.com/aTitle/aCatagory going to the exact same page if someone were to link to it the wrong way etc. Would search engines not then see this as duplicate content?

Comment: They won't be a duplicate since the latter will be a 404 since there won't be a page with a `cat` of "aTitle" and a `title` of "aCatagory".

Comment: Ohhh I see, now I understand, sorry it's just me being a bit stupid :/  Thanks for your help, it's really appreciated!